# How to move ID from an API in one component to another componet to use that ID for another API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I will apologize in advance for incorrect lingo, just started to code in Nov.

I am using this API (https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=)
to get idMeal, strMeal, strMealThumb from the objects, which is mapping over cards to populate different recipes. (Search Component)

I want the user to be able to click on it for them to go to another component that uses another API to populate the actual recipe( Recipe Component) with the id from the Search Component.
`www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${idMeal}`

Unsure how to proceed with this. Was thinking about using a React Router Link to jump to the other component, and need to make the idMeal into state to transfer from Search into Recipe.

Should I use Redux, Context or something else?

```
    export default function Search() {
  const [isSearched, setSearched] = useState("");
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
  const [isId, setId] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(isSearched);
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${isSearched}`
    );
    setMeals(res.data.meals);
  };
  useEffect(() => {}, [meals]);

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <ForkSpoonImg src={forkspoon} />
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Please Search an Ingredient</h2>
        <Input type="text" onInput={(e) => setSearched(e.target.value)}></Input>
        <Button type="submit">
          <SearchIcon />
        </Button>
      </form>
      <CardContainter>
        {meals.map(({ idMeal, strMeal, strMealThumb }, index) => {
          return (
            <Tag //<------- will change to Link, was just testing to see endpoint
              href={`www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${idMeal}`}
              key={index}
            >
              <Cards key={index} title={strMeal} url={strMealThumb} />
            </Tag>
          );
        })}
      </CardContainter>
    </PageContainer>
  );
}
```

Kindest Regards!

Comment: You can pass it as a prop to another component

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't I need to set state (id) in a parent component then?

Comment: there are many ways to do that and that is one of them, you can try it

Comment: If you app is for web page, when the page is refreshed, the props is lost. Then, you can put the id on the url and on your second component, take id from url. You can use react -router-dom or window history